# rails 4 ruby conditional based on ENV var and Rails.env.production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I am trying to setup a few global helper decision functions that look like this:

```
  def send_email_to_external_service
    ENV['SEND_EMAIL_TO_EXTERNAL_SERVICE']? true : false
  end
```

This works great for development, but obviously, I do not want to have to pass these parameters in for production so I had to roll with:

```
  def send_email_to_external_service
    active = ENV['SEND_EMAIL_TO_EXTERNAL_SERVICE']? true : false
    active = true if Rails.env.production?
    return active
  end
```

Would there be a better way of structuring this function i.e. is a single line possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do something like this:

```
def send_email_to_external_service
  Rails.env.production? || ENV['SEND_EMAIL_TO_EXTERNAL_SERVICE']
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is more what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: present? seems unnecessary since nil evaluates to false.